# Ошибка в php выполнении notice: ununitialize string offset on line

Tags: php

Есть скрипт:

```
    $number = "123";
    $sum = 0;
      for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($number); $i++) {
        $sum += $number[$i];
    }
    echo $sum;
```

При выполнении выдаёт ошибку notice:

> ununitialize string offset on line 4.

Не могу понять почему?

Comment: Замените `<=` на `<` так как указатель у вас выходит за пределы строки.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало)

Answer (score 2):

У вас в строке 3 символа (`strlen($number)` возвращает данное значение), и т.к. отсчет начинается с нуля, то они имеют индексы 0,1,2 соответственно.

В условии `for` вы начинаете с нуля, и условием `<=` говорит что нужно перебрать все символы с индексами от 0 до 3, включая сам индекс 3, которого, как написано выше, нет. Как только вы пытаетесь получить доступ к символу под индексом 3 то получаете ошибку.

Надо или изменить условие или уменьшить кол-во символов:

`for($i = 0; $i < strlen($number); $i++) {`

`for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($number)-1; $i++) {`